# ASP.NET Core MVC : how to maintain selected option through validation?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have form that has two dropdowns:

1. Select a user
2. Select an application

Upon submitting give the user access to that application

Some validation happens after to make sure the user doesn't already have access to that application (I don't want duplicates in the database). My issue is after the validation catches bad inputs and returns the error message the previously selected option disappears from the dropdown. See images for before and after.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEbSl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96DB4.png)

Here's the view:

```
@using UserManagement.Models.User;
@model IEnumerable<User>

@{
    var users = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var t in Model)
    {
        users.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName, Value = t.Id.ToString()});
    }
    users.Sort((left, right) => left.Text.CompareTo(right.Text));
}

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">User</label>

    @*
    1.Find out if a role was selected in the previous screen
    2.Find out if we need to update the table when they select a role
    *@
    @{
        bool hasSelected = false;
        if (users.Find(t => t.Text == ViewBag.User) is not null)
        {
            hasSelected = true;
        }

        string onchangeString = "";
        if (ViewBag.UpdateTable == 1)
        {
            onchangeString = "onchange = updateTableSelection();";
        }
    }
    <select class="form-control" id="ID" name="ID" @onchangeString>
        @* only show this if nothing was selected. Otherwise show the default option *@
        @if (!hasSelected)
        {
            <option value="" disabled selected>--Select a user--</option>
        }

        @foreach (var u in users)
        {
            @* add the selected tag to the role that the user had selected in the previous screen *@
            if (u.Text == ViewBag.User)
            {
                <option selected id="u.Text" value="@u.Value">@u.Text</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@u.Value">@u.Text</option>
            }
        }
    </select>

    @Html.ValidationMessage("ID", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
</div>
```

I tried using javascript to update the selected option but I can't seem to pin down where/when this is happening. Was hoping someone knew something about the selected attribute here that I don't.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you do not post images as links; instead, just paste where  you want it to show up.

Comment: When a validation error occurs, the form usually re-rendered, and the selected option is not being persisted in the dropdown.
However, if you want to  maintain the selected option after a validation error, you can use the `ModelState` dictionary to store the selected value and then retrieve it when re-rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design could be reworked. For example I would try not to show those values at all in drop down. Lets say userA has already AT&T, then AT&T should not even show up in dropdown or you should disable it at least.